# How to send a formatted date in angular

Tags: angular, date, format

I have a form and one of the inputs type is a date, which is formatted as 'dd/MM/yyyy', but the API which I'm posting only accepts date as 'MM/dd/yyyy'.

Can someone explain to me how can I transform this date before sending it to the API. I'm using angular 15.

My component looks like this:

```js
  criarInternacao() {
    this.service
        .postInternacao(this.dateToBeFormated)
        .subscribe((data:any) => {
          console.log('success')
        )
    });
  }
```

and the service looks like this:

```js
  public postInternacao(dateToBeFormated?: any) {
    const token = this.token.retornaToken();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });

    return this.http.post(
      `${APIINTERNACAO}/add-date/&dateToBeFormated=${ dateToBeFormated }`,
      {
        dateToBeFormated:dateToBeFormated,
      },
      { headers, observe: 'response' }
    )
  }
```

Comment: See: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-invent the wheel to format dates in Angular. Just use the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```js
class YourService {

  // Pipes aren't just for templates.
  // You can create an instance of a pipe anywhere
  datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');

  postInternacao(dateToBeFormated?: any) {

  const token = this.token.retornaToken();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });

  // use the date pipe to transform your value
  const formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(dateToBeFormated, 'MM/dd/yyyy');

  return this.http.post(
    `${ APIINTERNACAO }/add-date/&dateToBeFormated=${ formattedDate }`,
    {
      dateToBeFormated:dateToBeFormated,
    },
    { headers, observe: 'response' }
    )
  }

}
```

Of course, you can change the locale passed to the DatePipe if necessary.

Comment: I did it as you said, but it didn't work, the console gave me the following error: NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "21/01/2023" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: You may have to change your locale. The DatePipe expects to be passed a date, not a string